# How do I stop jQuery validate from validating automatically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have a textbox on which I have made an onblur script that takes the input and converts it into a date. I'm using jQuery validate-plugin to validate the input, but the problem is that the input from the user is often not valid until I've parsed it, which makes the automatic validation that jQuery validation makes, both redundant and unwanted.

How can I stop jQuery validate from validating automatically so I can run it only on demand?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#aspnetForm').validate({
       onfocusout: false,
       onkeyup: false,
       onclick: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Validate options page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

Disables onblur validation.

```
$(".selector").validate({
   onfocusout: false
})
```

Comment: I happened upon the answer in a link in an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707436/extending-jquery-validate-to-show-hide-div-or-clear-div-after-validate-is-ran